# Flask app.errorhandler not catching exceptions when running with Flask-CLI

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, error-handling, flask-cli

I am struggling to get my Flask application to properly handle errors when invoking the application using Flask-CLI.

Here is a simple file called `app_runner.py`:

```
import click
from flask import Flask
from flask_cli import FlaskCLI

app = Flask(__name__)
FlaskCLI(app)

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def catch_error(e):
    print('I wish I saw this')

@app.cli.command(with_appcontext=True)
def test_run():
    with app.app_context():
        print('You will see this')
        raise Exception
        print('You won\'t see this')
```

I invoke the `test_run` function via this bash command: `FLASK_APP=app_runner.py flask test_run`.

I see the first print statement 'You will see this', but I don't see the one that says 'I wish I saw this'.

I hit the `Exception`, but I never go into the code defined under `app.errorhandler`. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error handlers are only for errors raised while handling *views*. CLI commands are totally separate. If you want to handle an error in a Click command, you need to handle it as you would any Python exception: with a `try / except` block.